# Problem getting ROS environment variables with python

Tags: python, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to get the environment variables ROS_MASTER_URI ,ROS_IP and ROS_HOSTNAME with a python script to show it in some information screen for the user. When I open a terminal and echo myself them I get the expected result. But when I do the same with the script I don't get any values  like they were not set at all. I tried these ways already:

1. `print(os.environ.get("ROS_MASTER_URI"))`
2. `proc = subprocess.Popen('echo "$ROS_MASTER_URI"',shell=True, universal_newlines=True,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, executable="/bin/bash")`
3. `print(os.environ)`

Does anyone know why this is not working as expected ?
I'm using python version 3.5 and my ros version is kinetic on an ubuntu 16.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302474/problem-getting-ros-environment-variables-with-python/) by [Lycea](https://answers.ros.org/users/36240/lycea/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2018-09-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you starting your Python script from a `bash` session that has `source`d the relevant `setup.bash` file?

If not, then those variables will not be set and that would explain what you report.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lycea](https://answers.ros.org/users/36240/lycea/) on 2018-09-06**:
Thank you, that actually was the problem. I thought about it bevore but I was the opinion it already used the bashrc for initialisation.  After a small tweak with adding source it now worked :)

fixed with source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash;echo " $ROS_MASTER_URI"